# Is there anyway in webpack to pass some dynamic parameters to loader?

Tags: webpack

in Webpack for example

```
const query = {text: "test"};
require(`template/test.tpl?${query}`);
```

as you know, webpack could treat the sentence as a dynamic require which is running in runtime. but I need the `require('template/test.tpl?${query}');` running in buildtime.

is there any way to do that?

PS:

https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#via-require

`Options can be passed with a query parameter, just like on the web (?key=value&foo=bar). It's also possible to use a JSON object (?{"key":"value","foo":"bar"}).`

it seems that the query parameters must to be literal, is any way to be variable?

thanks for your reading.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I want to render the template into html on the buildtime instead of runtime. and the loader need some parameters to render the template to html

Answer (score 1):

OK,
It looks impossible with that, 
The owner of webpack answer the questions:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2992

Answer (score 0):

You can use `imports-loader` to pass some params to the file:

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/imports-loader/

`require("imports-loader?$=jquery!./example.js");`

About object, you can always use JSON.stringify for passing object and JSON.parse inside loaded file.

Comment: Thanks for your replying, but your solution is to pass the parameter to the required file. what I need is passing the parameter to loader